# Back To {AppName} Not Showing Up | iOS9 openURL

Tags: ios, ios9, deep-linking, openurl

I'm using the following code:

```
NSString *customURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"secondApp://?%@", [document fileId]];
NSURL *customURL = [NSURL URLWithString: customURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: customURL];
```

The "Back To firstApp" is not showing up upon successful opening of the secondApp. Is there something I'm missing? Been scouring the internet for this answer, and am trying to make sure that "Back To firstApp" is there.

Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer.

Apparently, if you put this in your info.plist for the second app,
  [image]

and declare that View controller-based status bar appearance is NO. It will not show the back to button. Not quite sure why, but this resolved my issue.

Thank you everyone for the support!

Comment: Looks like I am currently experiencing this same issue but exclusive to iPad devices. Ever find a good explanation or do you assume this is an OS bug? I can fix it exactly as you described.

Answer (score 1):

**Worth checking**: "Back to ..." appear only when statusBar is visible. Are you sure your second app show statusBar?

The only explanation that came to my mind is that your second app can use depracated fullscreen launch method. Please check if:

Your code is fine, please check if this gave you this desired behaviour.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://stackoverflow.com"]];
```

If so, there is a problem with your second app.

Comment: Where would I go to check this? It is showing the status bar, but where do I go to check the full screen launch method?

Comment: Nevermind, found it. I'm not using the full screen launch and it is visible at launch.

Answer (score 1):

**Set your Destination application's info.plist like this.**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>Myapp</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.Myapp.demo</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>Myapp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

**Put this method in your destination app's AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return YES;
}
```

**Now from you source application open destination app using this.**

```
NSString *customURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Myapp://"];
NSURL *customURL = [NSURL URLWithString: customURLString];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: customURL];
```

This will surely show **Back To App** on status bar.

You can also check by typing **Myapp://** from **Safari**. it will open your app with **Back To Safari**.

Comment: This is exactly what I have, and it's not working >_<

Comment: But, its working in my application. May be you are missing something.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it from Safari, and it's not saying back to safari either.